# How to set Primary key to 1 after delete table data?

Tags: sql-server

I have a SQL Table named logindetails, it has 3 columns UserID ( set as primary and Is Identity as Yes), UserName and Password. I have inserted values to the table. But after the query "delete from logindetails" all data from the table except the UserID is deleted. Whenever I enter new data the ID will not be 1 and it is one greater than the last inserted ID. I need to automatically set it to 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `DBCC CHECKIDENT` ([documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176057.aspx)) command to change the next identity value:

```
DBCC CHECKIDENT (logindetails, reseed, 0)
```

In case there are no foreign keys referencing the table, you can use `TRUNCATE TABLE` ([documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177570.aspx)), which will reset the identity column:

```
TRUNCATE TABLE logindetails
```

Comment: 1 will cause the next value to be 2, unless it's a brand new table.

Comment: @ta.speot.is: Whops. Fixed.

Comment: also `truncate` does this automatically

Comment: @bansi: True, but that requires that there is no foreign keys. But I'll add that, it is a good point.